# apache wont start when virtual hosts are defined

Tags: apache-2.2, centos, virtualhost

I have setup up virtualnamehosts on my server and I do not recieve any errors when starting apache but when I check to see if it has started it says:

```
httpd dead but pid file exists
```

thanks for the help.

also here is my config:

```
#
# Use name-based virtual hosting.
#
NameVirtualHost *:80
#
# NOTE: NameVirtualHost cannot be used without a port specifier 
# (e.g. :80) if mod_ssl is being used, due to the nature of the
# SSL protocol.
#

#
# VirtualHost example:
# Almost any Apache directive may go into a VirtualHost container.
# The first VirtualHost section is used for requests without a known
# server name.
#
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot /var/www/html
ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin blah@blah.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/html
ServerName mysite.com
ServerAlias www.mysite.com
ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/mysite.com/error_log
CustomLog /var/log/httpd/mysite/access_log common
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin blah@blah.com 
DocumentRoot /var/www/savvyParts
ServerName mysite2.com
ServerAlias www.mysite2.com
ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/mysite2.com/error_log
CustomLog /var/log/httpd/mysite2.com/access_log common
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Error log says...?

Comment: You should really look in the apache error log. ´/var/log/httpd´ or something like that.

Comment: turns out it couldnt find my error log folder thanks guys

Comment: hah. I was just posting about the path problem in the config you pasted, and you got there before me.

Answer (score 0):

To test the config for correctness you use the following command;

```
 # service httpd configtest
 Syntax OK
```

I tried your test config and I got some path errors;

```
# service httpd configtest
Warning: DocumentRoot [/var/www/savvyParts] does not exist
Syntax OK
```

and it wouldn't start after that.

**So First** *Check the paths for your  DocumentRoot and paths actually exists*

If this does not fix the problem then you should provide the output of the following command;

```
 # cat /var/log/httpd/error_log

[Thu May 10 05:22:00 2012] [notice] Digest: done
[Thu May 10 05:22:00 2012] [notice] SSL FIPS mode disabled
[Thu May 10 05:22:00 2012] [notice] Apache/2.2.22 (Unix) DAV/2 PHP/5.3.11 mod_ssl/2.2.22 OpenSSL/1.0.0h-fips configured -- resuming normal operations
```

also you can start httpd from the command line as root, and watch for any other startup errors;

```
# /usr/sbin/httpd
(98)Address already in use: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:80
(98)Address already in use: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80
no listening sockets available, shutting down
Unable to open logs
```

Comment: Well of course `/var/www/savvyParts` is not going to exist on your server.

Comment: oops. me feel silly.

Comment: I bet you do. :)

Comment: interesting, i just tried `configtest` and it doesn't appear to test the Log directories until something needs to be logged, so I would be interested in a check for that